# Two instances of Scanner in Java gives an error

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The title says my question.
Here's my code

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        String name = sc2.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Test = " + x + name);
    }
}
```

and it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

If I just use one scanner which is `sc`, the code works. My Java version is SDK v.13.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need two separate scanners? One scanner can do both `nextInt` and `nextLine`.
Two scanners is redundant.

The problem is both instances use the same InputStream.

Solution: use one Scanner.